# 'JavaScriptSerializer' could not be found .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, javascriptserializer

when trying to initialize a variable

```
JavaScriptSerializer javascriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

I am getting the following error : 'JavaScriptSerializer' could not be found .net core.
i also tried to include the namespace 'System.Web.Script.Serialization' but even that is not found.

How to solve it?

Comment: that doesn't exist in .net core. use JSON.NET

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: converting one of my .net project to .net core. there i faced this issue. so  i don't want to use 'JsonConvert'

Comment: You should not introduce an System.Web dependency on a .NET Core project. If a new project you should use .NET Core 2.0 + and Newtonsoft.Json comes with it. If you are not able to use Newtonsoft.Json even installing via NuGet it and seeing the dependency I think your problem is another

Answer (score 1):

Adding it via `Nuget` may solve your problem. Open the `Nuget` package manager and type in the following command:

```
Install-Package WebApiContrib.Formatting.JavaScriptSerializer
```

Edit:

`Newtonsoft.Json` is the standard nowadays. It is also known as `Json.Net`.

Comment: @AdithyaSai: Use `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: I cant find an JavaScriptSerializer in that package only, JavaScriptSerializerFormatter. I'm using dotnet core 6.